# PySpark get value of dataframe column with max date

Tags: pyspark

I need to create a new column in a pyspark dataframe using a column value from the row of the max date over a window. Given the dataframe below, I need to set a new column called max_adj_factor on each record for each assetId based on the adjustment factor of the most recent date.

```
+----------------+-------+----------+-----+
|adjustmentFactor|assetId|      date|  nav|
+----------------+-------+----------+-----+
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-20| 18.5|
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-23|18.67|
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-24| 18.6|
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-26|18.57|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2019-12-27|18.46|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2019-12-30|18.41|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2019-12-31|18.34|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-02|18.77|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-03|19.07|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-06|19.16|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-07| 19.2|
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [max_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#max_by) over a [Window](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html?pyspark.sql.Window):

```python
df.withColumn("max_adj_factor", \
        F.expr("max_by(adjustmentFactor, date)") \
        .over(Window.partitionBy("assetId"))) \
        .show()
```

Output:

```
+----------------+-------+----------+-----+----------------+
|adjustmentFactor|assetId|      date|  nav|  max_adj_factor|
+----------------+-------+----------+-----+----------------+
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-20| 18.5|10.0449181987999|
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-23|18.67|10.0449181987999|
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-24| 18.6|10.0449181987999|
|9.96288362069999|4000123|2019-12-26|18.57|10.0449181987999|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2019-12-27|18.46|10.0449181987999|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2019-12-30|18.41|10.0449181987999|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2019-12-31|18.34|10.0449181987999|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-02|18.77|10.0449181987999|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-03|19.07|10.0449181987999|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-06|19.16|10.0449181987999|
|10.0449181987999|4000123|2020-01-07| 19.2|10.0449181987999|
+----------------+-------+----------+-----+----------------+
```

Comment: Nice! FYI - pyspark 3.1+ required